# Jquery.each throwing error: possible Json to string conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, each

Hi i need to iterate over each title in this code. However, i'm getting some error in console that states cannot use 'in' operator.  This code works fine when i pass an id that is coming from database.  But i need to pass in a string, then it throws error right after each function is called.  I can't figure out why, one thing i can think of is there is possible JSON/string conflic.  How do i resolve that. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

```
   function getFilteredBySearch(searchString){      

              return priv.availablePrintables.filter(function(printableModel) {               
                var result = false;               
                var title = printableModel.getTitle();              
                  $.each(title, function(idx, id) {

                    if (id == searchString) {
                        result = true;
                        return false;   // break out of the 'each' loop
                    }                  
                })
                return result;  // return from the callback
            });
        }
```

RESOLVED:

The following worked!

```
  if ((printableModel.getTitle()).indexOf(searchString) > -1){
                result = true;
                console.log(result);
              }
```

Comment: what printableModel.getTitle() returns?

Comment: it returns title as coloring book for example.  it returns plain text coloring book in console.log.  
If i use getCategories() it return it formatted ["book"] in console.log

Comment: I assume title is type of string so how do you want to iterate with $.each method over string?

Comment: i need to match title with the searchString.  searchString is the value that is typed in the search box, and title is a model attribute

Comment: because there are many titles and i need to check on each title.  am i doing something wrong?

Comment: please, mark one of our answers as correct if it helped

Comment: Ok will do so. i'll mark them

Comment: you've obviously used my solution and marked as correct another answer. well done, Sherolock, well done '-_-

Comment: @Jimmyweb, Mike pointed out that " think you're trying to iterate over the collection, when the filter method already does that for you. You don't need jQuery to loop over a number of items, when you only have one to examine."
The latter statement helped me immensely in fixing the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to iterate over the collection, when the filter method already does that for you. You don't need jQuery to loop over a number of items, when you only have one to examine. Try this:

```
function getFilteredBySearch(searchString){      

    return priv.availablePrintables.filter(function(printableModel) {               

      return (searchString == printableModel.getTitle());              
    });
}
```

(I'm not that familiar with backbone.js, so I might have the syntax slightly wrong)

Answer (score 1):

This is only made based on assumptions: probably sometimes `getTitle` method return string and sometimes returns array of strings (because you've pointed out that console logs out `["book"]` when you get title). You can check what type of object it returns:

```
function getFilteredBySearch(searchString){      

      return priv.availablePrintables.filter(function(printableModel) {                            
        var title = printableModel.getTitle();
            if(typeof title == 'string'){
                //if it's string
                return (title == searchString);
            }else{
                //if it's array
                return (title.indexOf(searchString) != -1);
            }
    });
}
```